# show snack bar message in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, snackbar

Is there a way to show an `HStack` like a snack bar message which dismisses after (n) seconds using SwiftUI ?

I have the following struct which's a container to my message:

```
struct MessageBuilder<Content>: View where Content: View {

    let content: () -> Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        content()
    }
}
```

I call the `MessageBuilder` struct like following:

```
MessageBuilder {
            HStack {
                Image("MyImage")
                Text("Some Message")
            }
        }
```

I got two questions:

(1) how can I show it on top of screen and then auto-dismiss it (like [SwiftMessages](https://github.com/SwiftKickMobile/SwiftMessages)) ?

(2) how can I write a wrapper function that displays the message above any SwiftUI `View`, for ex. in a `Storyboard` based projects we would pass something like topViewController or `rootViewController` in order to show a `UIView` on top of it.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `ViewModifier` to create the banner view and then call it as modifier in your SwiftUI.
Using ZStack in your modifier to present the banner on top of your content.
Here is the simple example for create a banner and show on top of the view

in your view you can use `.banner(data: $bannerData, show: $showBanner)` to present the banner

```swift
struct BannerData {
        var title: String
        var detail: String
        var type: BannerType
    }

    enum BannerType {
        case info
        case warning
        case success
        case error

        var tintColor: Color {
            switch self {
            case .info:
                return Color(red: 67/255, green: 154/255, blue: 215/255)
            case .success:
                return Color.green
            case .warning:
                return Color.yellow
            case .error:
                return Color.red
            }
        }
    }

struct BannerModifier: ViewModifier {

    @Binding var data: BannerData
    @Binding var show: Bool


    @State var task: DispatchWorkItem?

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            if show {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                            Text(data.title)
                                .bold()
                            Text(data.detail)
                                .font(Font.system(size: 15, weight: Font.Weight.light, design: Font.Design.default))
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .padding(12)
                    .background(data.type.tintColor)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .shadow(radius: 20)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding()
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.2))
                .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .top).combined(with: .opacity))

                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.show = false
                    }
                }.onAppear {
                    self.task = DispatchWorkItem {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.show = false
                        }
                    }
                    // Auto dismiss after 5 seconds, and cancel the task if view disappear before the auto dismiss
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5, execute: self.task!)
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    self.task?.cancel()
                }
            }
            content
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func banner(data: Binding<BannerData>, show: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        self.modifier(BannerModifier(data: data, show: show))
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a nice and simple implementation, however, the message background view is semi-transparent, I've tried to change all colors with opacity values but to no avail, do you have a clue on how to make its background to have a solid color not semi-transparent ?

Comment: I didn't understand. in the example above the banner background is solid with a shadow behind it and not semi-transparent when it's present on content

Comment: it was because the view showing the message was under a VStack

Comment: If I have a View that is only a `VStack` or `ZStack`, when I use BannerModifier on each of those Views it won't Appear if I used it like this: `ZStack {...}.banner(..)`  or `VStack{...}.banner(...)`, to make it work I have to always use a `ZStack` for my setup and I have to put the following line as the last element in the `ZStack`:   `EmptyView().banner(...)` , can you show the banner directly on any kind of view without needing to use this workaround ?

Comment: @JAHelia solution to your problem is zIndex(_:). By default the value for zIndex is 0(Zero). You can provide a positive or negative value to arrange the overlapping of views.
Link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/group/3284926-zindex

Comment: @Mac3n can you add zIndex to your bannerView so that it appears even when using NavihationView etc.

Comment: I don't understand about zIndex, my banner is not showing up :( I applied `.banner` to a List.

Answer (score -3):

I have created below utility, Easy to use and supports all presenting directions and action buttons:

https://github.com/indrajitv/ICToastMessage

Usage:

```
struct StraightForward: View {

    @State
    var show: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show") {
                self.show = true
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .setToastMessage(show: $show, text: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.")
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34764404)

Comment: If the link changes, the Solution is no more useful. I do not agree with the suggestion. You are forcing me to delete the answer.